# Laravel 5 validation is not working

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1

My route code looks like this

```
Route::post('doCheckIn', 'TransactionController@store');
```

My store in Controller looks like this, I'm trying to do room checking in...

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        for ($x=1; $x<=$request->num; $x++)
        {
            if($request->input('guest_name'.$x) == "")
            {
                //echo 'here';
            }
            $this->validate($request, [
            'guest_name'.$x => 'required',
            'room_num'.$x => 'required',
            'check_in'.$x => 'required',
            'check_out'.$x => 'required',
            ]);
        }
```

As you can see there is an if statement in my store function which works perfectly fine when I comment out the `this->validate(...)`. It echoes on the page. But it won't work when I get rid of the comment and try to validate the form. Meaning the validate function doesn't even work. 
the page shows

> `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:`

I tried making another Laravel project and running it in a separate page and it worked. The problem is all my codes are in this project folder. I'm stuck! Anybody please help. Is there any class that I must use prior to using validate?

Update...
Here is my form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Check In</title>
        <!--CSS And JavaScript -->

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Check in</h1>

        </table>
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
    <form action="doCheckIn" method="POST">
    <tr><td><input type="hidden"  id="num" name="num" value="{{$numroom}}"/></td></tr>
    @for ($x=1;$x<=$numroom; $x++)
    <tr>
        <td>Guest Name:</td>
        <td>
                    <input  type="text" id="guest_name{{$x}}" 
                            name="guest_name{{$x}}"/><div id="guest_namewarn1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Room Number:</td>
        <td><input type="text"  id="room_num{{$x}}"   
                           name="room_num{{$x}}" size="5" maxlength="4"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Check In:</td>
        <td><input type="date"  id="check_in{{$x}}" value="2015-12-04" name="check_in{{$x}}"/></div></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Check out:</td>
                <td><input type="date"  id="check_out{{$x}}"  name="check_out{{$x}}"/><br><br></td>

    </tr>
    @endfor
        {{csrf_field()}}
    <tr><td>
                <input type="submit" id="s_button" value="Check in" ><br><br><button type="button" name="back" onclick="goBack()">Kembali</button>
        </td></tr>

    </form>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML code for your form? Check to make sure it's using the POST method to match your route.

Comment: Share your `Form`, most probably the problem is in your form method as @mopo922 said.

Comment: Check `php artisan route:list` to make sure your POST route is showing up. And if `action="doCheckIn"` is happening on a URL like `something/123` it's going to be POSTing to `something/doCheckIn`. Consider `action="{{ url('doCheckIn') }}"` instead.

Comment: @ceejayoz it's still not working unfortunately.

Comment: @KurtNovice What's the URL of the page showing the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` exception message?